# svn diff outputs incorrect result

Tags: svn

I am attempting to diff two files using the following command:

```
svn diff -r 6382:6383 RepositoryURL --extensions -U0
```

The output result is very strange, it shows that the entire file is modified:

```
@@ -1,1233 +1,1228 @@
```

For a file which has 1233 lines to start with and at the end has 1228 lines after modifications take place. These modifications are however localized (a few lines here, a few lines there) while the bulk of the file remains identical.

This is also confirmed when I open it using the GUI by doing right-click repo> TortoiseSVN>Show log>navigate to appropriate revision>open in TortoiseMerge.

In TortoiseMerge it only shows the modified lines being highlighted, and not the entire file. Also if I "Create a patch file" from TortoiseMerge I get the exact same result as from my command:

```
@@ -1,1233 +1,1228 @@
```

Why does the `diff` functionality show that the whole file is modified while in TortoiseMerge I am getting what I deem to be the correct result? I am thinking perhaps the user edited the file in a Notepad program and then copied it over, but still it should be able to detect that the lines are the same....

Please note I cannot share the source code because of confidentiality restrictions, and so I am relying on the experience of someone who is well versed in `svn`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When `diff` thinks that a file has changed completely, there are usually two potential reasons:

1. Line endings. The different operating systems have a "different opinion" how a line ending should look alike: `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r`. Most developer tools allow to ignore such changes, but sometime the setting is not applied consistently in all tools. Check the original and the updated source code file in a hex editor to see if there are differences regarding the line endings.
2. White space changes: Source code is usually indented using spaces or tabs. Some IDE editors automatically reformat code to the one or the other. Therfore the code my look the same but the white space indentation characters has been replaced.